# Django override ManyRelatedManager

Tags: python, django

I've a standard User, Friendship model in my Django application.

In the User model I have defined the "friends" ManyToMany field with self relation through Friendship model.

```
    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
        friends = models.ManyToManyField("self", through="Friendship",
                                 symmetrical=False, blank=True, verbose_name="Friends")
    class Friendship(models.Model):
        friendship_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
        from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="+")
        to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="+")
```

If I implement the symmetric relation, with manually call twice the save() method of Friendship, the code:  **myUserObject.friends.all()** return all friends.

But, if don't implements the symmetric relation and user1 and user2 are friends, only **user1.friends.all()** return me user2..... user2.friends.all() doesn't return anything.

Since user1.friends is ManyRelatedManager, I need to override this manager to reimplement  the search function logic (ex: with Q object for search in from_user and to_user field).

The solution to add get_friends(self) to my Model doesn't seems ok...
Can I use @property decorator for friends field?
Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use the `through` attribute: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Through is a parameter of ManyToManyField...

Comment: @Joren, can you explain me what do you mean?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use it as a symmetric relation?  That seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?